# writing keys of a dictionary to a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

How can i write keys of a dictionary to a text file line by line, i.e. one key per line? If there is any link pointing to the same, please direct me to that link. I can find loading text file contents into a dictionary, but i am not able to find the vice-versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want to print is the keys (i.e. not the values) you can simply iterate over the dict:

```
with open("filename", "w") as f:
    for key in dict:
        print >>f, key
```

or in Python 3, with the new print function:

```
with open("filename", "w") as f:
    for key in dict:
        print(key, file=f)
```

Answer (score 0):

At the bare minimum, something like this will work:

```
fp = open('filename','w');
for k,v in myDict.items():
 fp.write('%s=%s\n', k, v);
 #for writing just the key per line
 #fp.write('%s\n',k);

fp.close();
```

you might need sanity checks for presence of '=' in key and escaping '\r' '\n' in value with \r and \n